# Run Nosestests on the tests folder and get coverage just for files in the src folder

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

My project has the following structure:

```
Project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __main__.py
    ├── test
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── my_mocker.py
    │   ├── test_first_module.py
    │   ├── test_second_module.py
    │   ├── ...
    │   └── test_nth_module.py
    └── src
        ├── first_module.py
        ├── second_module.py
        ├── ...
        └── nth_module.py
```

I want to run nosetests on the tests in the `tests` directory. The tests have all the filename structure `test_*` and I want to use --with-coverage but only get the result on the files in the `src` folder.
All tests are written with `unittest`.
Can somebody help me to say how the command line of nonetests should look like. I have checked everything without success. I am getting in the coverage also all site-packages files.

Comment: *nosetests*, *nonetests* could you specify what stand for? could you add some details?